# On-screen Hebrew keyboard pops up for no reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Even as I'm typing this it has done it again. Every time I click into the text box to form an answer, ask a question, or edit a post, the on-screen Hebrew keyboard pops up for no reason, and remains there even after I've exited the box. Why is it doing this?

[image]

This is *extremely* annoying and I'd like to have this sorted out. Does this have anything to do with the new Mi Yodeya theme at all? If so, this is a bug that *definitely* needs sorting out.

Comment: I just noticed this as well and was thinking of posting about it.

Comment: It just popped up for me when I tried to vote on this question!  (I moved it aside so I could vote, but I can't dismiss it.)  But it didn't happen when I just voted on a question on main.  Are you seeing this on both main and meta, or only on meta?

Comment: Ok, I've found one way to reproduce it: *while a post box (question or answer) has focus*, clicking on the site switcher, achievements, inbox, or my user profile link in the topbar reliably brings the keyboard up for me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Great, now I have a Hebrew keyboard floating in the corner covering the screen. :P

Comment: Huh, this is super strange. I’ll check it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ezra good news; if I then toggle the keyboard control on the post (seems to require a couple clicks, one to summon it even though it's already there, and then one to dismiss it), it doesn't come back.  Refreshing the page means you start over, though.

Comment: For me it disappeared once I posted the answer I was typing. And it appears when I am in the answer box, go to a different tab, and then come back to the answer box.

Comment: @Alex Even still it's super annoying

Comment: @ezra I agree. I'm just noting the parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about that. I have a fix ready and queued up for deployment to production. Unfortunately, our full prod builds are currently blocked on testing [a major infrastructure change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316278/the-road-to-net-core-please-help-stack-exchange-test-ef-core). That should clear up sometime between later today and end of tomorrow, but I don't have a specific time at the moment.

In the meantime, I apologize for the annoyance and the inconvenience - it looks like my keyboard layout/positioning fixes from yesterday unmasked this problem, but I didn't notice it in my local testing.

**Update:** the fixes have been deployed. Please let me know if there are any other keyboard issues.

Comment: Thanks a billion, Adam!